# Using hash sign (#) in the Excel sheet name

Tags: excel, oledb

I'm trying to solve an issue I have when I'm trying to use OLE DB for reading Excel files.
I found that the problem is because there is a **hash mark (#)** in the **sheet name**.

Unfortunately, I can't rename the sheet.

So after some tries, I've succeeded to read a full sheet by adding quotation marks ('):

**Before**

```
Select * from [" + sheetName + "$];
```

**After (working)**

```
Select * from ['" + sheetName + "$'];
```

But then I got stuck when trying to read a **range** from the sheet with the OLE DB feature:

```
Select * from [" + sheetName + "$" + fromCell + ":" + toCell + "];
```

When I try to send this command, it's seems like the `#` is replaced by `.` and then it cannot find the sheet.

I've tried many combination and escape codes and didn't find any solution. How can I access this file?

Comment: I have provided the format you need for your `sql` to make the range work in my answer. Also what you need to know is that different versions of **Microsoft Office Access database engine** handle the ranges in their `commmand` differently. So if you could stick to the latest (2010 atm) specially if you're going to use Active Ranges and ranges with the Worksheet scope rather than global workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your final output should look like this

```
'MySheet$A1:B2'
```

So your `select` should be

```
var SheetName = "MySheet";
var fromCell = "A1";
var toCell = "B2";
var sql = "Select * from ['" + SheetName + "$" + fromCell + ":" + toCell + "']";
Console.WriteLine(sql);

// Output
// Select * from ['MySheet$A1:B2']
```

Also consider parametrising your sql for better readability and also preventing *sql code injection*. You can find a guide for how to do it at [OleDbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).